# Creating custom keyboard with spelling for Android

Tags: android, keyboard

I would like to create my keyboard with corrective and spelling for using in every application or website on my device. Please suggest me about how possible and reference of my project.

Comment: Since Google is obviously not working, the [Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html) has a full guide on how to create IMEs together with a complete [SoftKeyboard](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard) sample app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an [InputMethodService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html) and it will work on all apps.

> There is a lot of explanation. But i will include some basic. let me know if you have any confusion.

Read this tutorial  [**create an InputMethod**](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-input-method.html) and then go through the [second one](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html)

And two great tutorial are [**this**](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm) and [**openSource LatinIME**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME)

Answer (score 0):

**Spelling Checker Framework**
The Android platform offers a spelling checker framework that lets you implement and access spell checking in your application. The framework is one of the Text Service APIs offered by the Android platform.

To use the framework in your app, you create a special type of Android service that generates a spelling checker session object. Based on text you provide, the session object returns spelling suggestions generated by the spelling checker.
you can see this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework.html